# Non-commutative simple group operates non-trivially on a set with less than $5$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, simple-groups

> Either prove or disprove that a non-commutative simple group can or cannot operate non-trivially on a set with less than $5$ elements.

What does the term "operate on a set" mean? And also "operate trivially"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\rho : G\longrightarrow {\rm Aut}(X)$ is a group action with $G$ simple. If $\rho$ is nontrivial, the fact that $G$ is simple means $\ker\rho=0$, that is, the action is faithful. If $|X|=n$; then $G$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(X)$, which has $n!$ elements. Now if $n<5$; then $n!=1,2,6,24$, so that the order of $G$ is a divisor of $24$. But [the smallest nonabelian simple group has order $5!/2=60$.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/A5_is_the_unique_simple_non-abelian_group_of_smallest_order)

Comment: How do you know that $G$ is necessarily a subgroup of Aut$(X)$, and that Aut$(X)$ necessarily has exactly $n!$ elements?

Comment: @morphic If a group morphism has zero kernel it is injective, and conversely. When I say "$A$ is a subgroup of $B$", I mean there is an injective group morphism $A\to B$. The notation ${\rm Aut}(X)$ stands for the bijections $X\to X$. If $X$ has $n$ elements, it is a matter of counting to notice there are exactly $n!$ bijections, which is the number of permutations of $n$ elements.

Comment: When you say "$G$ is a subgroup of Aut$(X)$", does it actually mean that $\rho(G)$ is a subgroup of Aut$(X)$, but $\rho(G)$ is isomorphic to $G$ because $\rho$ is injective?

Comment: @morphic Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).

The symmetric group $S_3$ (containing all permutations of $3$ elements) is noncommutative and acts on $3$ elements *nontrivially*, which means that not every group element performs the identity action. 
However, it is *not simple*, so we're not there yet.

A further hint: see the [list of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups)