# If a group $G$ has $|G| = n$ elements, when does $\text{Aut}(G)$ have $n!$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For some problems like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1455726/130018), we know that $\text{Aut}(G)$ has exactly $n!$ elements, but in other problems like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1474294/130018), $\text{Aut}(G)$ has less than $n!$ elements. How do you know in general how many elements $\text{Aut}(G)$ has? Like why in the first link we know exactly $n!$ elements without thinking, but in the second link we had to analyze to determine that $|\text{Aut}(G)| \neq |\text{Sym}(G)|$?

Comment: All automorphism can be considered as an element of $S_n$, so $|\text{Aut}(G)| \le n!$. However, it could not be equality as all automorphisms must fix the identity in $G$.

Comment: Right, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ can only have $n!$ elements if $G$ is the trivial group.  Otherwise there exists a permutation of the elements of $G$ that fails to fix the identity, and such a permutation can't be an automorphism.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $(n-1) !$ ?

Comment: @BrianO I was just going by the answer posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1455726/130018 I assumed the answer is correct (considering the person who answered it), but maybe there is an error. Their answer says that if $|X| = n$, then $\text{Aut}(X)$ has $n!$ elements since it is the number of bijections from $X$ to itself (or the symmetry group of order $n$).

Comment: In the first linked question, $X$ was merely a set. Having no algebraic structure (like being a group) its automorphism group consisted of every permutation of $X$.

Comment: Wow, that clears everything up. Thank you @pjs36

Comment: For BrianO's version, $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)| = (n-1)!$, the only other groups that work are $\mathbb Z/2$, $\mathbb Z/3$, and the Klein four-group.  Proof:  $\mathbb Z/4$ doesn't work, so suppose $|G| > 4$.  Let $g$ and $h$ be non-identity non-inverses.  Then we have distinct elements $1, g, h, gh$, and some other element $k$.  The permutation switching $gh$ and $k$ but fixing everything else is not an automorphism, so $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a proper subset of the permutations of the non-identity elements and has order strictly less than $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's an answer (although I'm by no means an expert):

In the first linked question, $X$ was just a set, and so its automorphism group was every single permutation of $X$, no questions asked.

This is generally *not* the case, although $n!$ is an *upper bound* for the number of automorphisms of a finite group of order $n$ (Since automorphisms are bijections, just with added structure).